# SQL Count for Each Category

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I need to count rows based on 2 fields for grouping.

#### Animals (a)

```
id     group_id   strain_id     death_date     death_cause   status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1      512        164           2015-12-01     Culled        P
2      512        164           2015-12-02     Culled        A
3      512        164           2015-12-02     Surplus       B
4      512        230           2015-12-06     Culled        A
5      512        164           2015-12-28     Culled        A
6      512        230           2016-01-20     Culled        B
7      512        230           2016-01-20     Surplus       P
8      512        164           NULL           NULL          P
9      512        230           NULL           NULL          B
10     512        230           NULL           NULL          A
11     512        164           2016-01-25     Culled        B
12     512        164           2016-02-29     Culled        A
13     512        230           2016-02-03     Surplus       P
14     512        230           2016-02-03     Culled        A
```

#### Groups (g)

```
id     group_name
--------------
512    Mice
```

#### Strain (s)

```
id     strain_name
----------------
164    Strain 1
230    Strain 2
```

#### Group Animal Count (gac)

```
id     total_animals      alive_count       dead_count
----------------------------------------------------------------------
512    14                 3                 11
```

#### Mating History (mh)

```
id     animal_id     history_type      history_date
--------------------------------------------------------
1001   2             MA                2015-11-20
1002   2             MR                2015-12-01
1003   3             MA                2015-12-01
1004   6             FA                2015-12-21
1005   9             FA                2016-02-07
1006   10            MA                2016-01-27
1007   11            FA                2015-12-12
```

So when I group them by the `strain_id` and the `death_cause` this is what they should look like visually:

#### Strain 1 ---- Culled

```
1      512        164           2015-12-01     Culled        P
2      512        164           2015-12-02     Culled        A
5      512        164           2015-12-28     Culled        A
11     512        164           2016-01-25     Culled        B
12     512        164           2016-02-29     Culled        A
```

#### Strain 1 ---- Surplus

```
3      512        164           2015-12-02     Surplus       B
```

#### Strain 2 ---- Culled

```
4      512        230           2015-12-06     Culled        A
6      512        230           2016-01-20     Culled        B
14     512        230           2016-02-03     Culled        A
```

#### Strain 2 ---- Surplus

```
7      512        230           2016-01-20     Surplus       P
13     512        230           2016-02-03     Surplus       P
```

What I want to get from the SQL query is the following result:

```
g_name  s_name    d_cause  a_total  c_alive  c_dead  c_pup  c_breeder  c_total
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mice    Strain 1  Culled   12       3        9       1      2          5
Mice    Strain 1  Surplus  12       3        9       0      1          1
Mice    Strain 2  Culled   12       3        9       0      1          3
Mice    Strain 2  Surplus  12       3        9       2      0          2
```

Basically I want to count the number of animals using 2 categories which in this case is the `strain_name` and the `death_cause`

Note that for an animal to be counted as a breeder (`c_breeder`), I have to look at the Mating History table and check if the `animal_id` has ever had any of these codes `MA` or `FA`.

I am using `INNER JOIN` on the `groups`, `group_animal_count`, and `strains`. I use `LEFT JOIN` for `mating_history` since animals with a status of `P` won't have records in that table since they're just pups and won't be involved with mating.

Comment: Is this the *exact* query you are using, or is there some `LEFT JOIN` also involved?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos There are 3 `INNER JOIN`s and 1 `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: You have to give us some additional info. The issue you are facing is not reproducible with the table structure, sample data and query provided.

Comment: Ok, give me a couple minutes I'll try to redo the question.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I've updated the question, I think this one is much closer to what I am actually doing.

Comment: Can't you just group by group_name, strain_name, death_cause (use inner joins to join the tables) and then count the death_dates?

Comment: I think there is still something missing from he mock-up you've setup.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I see the issue now. I tried @kordirko's solution and it seems to work without the `LEFT JOIN` but when I add the `LEFT JOIN` the amount becomes erroneous. I'll update the question again this time I'll try to include everything.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I now updated the question, I am using `INNER JOIN` on the `groups`, `group_animal_count`, and `strains`. I use `LEFT JOIN` for `mating_history` since animals with a status of `P` won't have records in that table.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT group_name, strain_name,death_cause, count(*) as Total
FROM ANIMALS a
JOIN GROUPS g ON a.group_id = g.id
JOIN STRAIN s ON a.strain_id = s.id
GROUP BY group_name, strain_name,death_cause
```

Comment: Your solution and @maraca's seem to give the same results. I have to verify it tomorrow. I'm about to get out of the office. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @SaravanakumarVadivel I've updated the question again to be as detailed as possible. This solution did work but my original question didn't include all the `joins` I was doing in my query. The moment I added everything in, the numbers didn't match. Please take a look again. Hopefully my updated question would show what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the aggregation before joining the tables:

```
SELECT group_name, strain_name, death_cause, total
FROM   (
         SELECT   group_id,
                  strain_id,
                  death_cause,
                  COUNT(*) AS total
         FROM     animals
         GROUP BY group_id, strain_id, death_cause
       ) a
       INNER JOIN groups g ON ( g.group_id = a.group_id )
       INNER JOIN strain s ON ( s.strain_id = a.strain_id );
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried this and it seems to be working but when I added a `LEFT JOIN` the numbers didn't add up anymore. I updated the question to be as detailed as possible so please take a look again. Hope you could help me out.